# Page become unresponsive after API called in ForEach angular

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, observable, es6-promise

I am selecting some links in my DOM element and iterating it in a forEach loop . By doing this my page become unresponsive for about 1-2 minute. I am trying to get the data from an external API(Not in my server) . The foreach iterates normally for 30-40 times.
This is my code

```
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".class0 > .class1 >.href-link")).forEach(function (item) {
        var api_url = item.getAttribute("href")
        this.http.post(api_url).pipe(takeUntil(that._destroyed$)).subscribe((data: any) => {
            // I have some action to be performed on the result of each API
        })
    });
```

I need this API to be called one after another.I need to call the APIs only if the previous API have finished its execution

Comment: i would advice you to try to isolate the problem by making a single api call to know if it comes from it firstly and to see how long it takes.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon yes i have done that.The response time varies.On average the responce time is .5 sec.My issue is that all the api's are called together.and if i check the console i can find that over 30 apis are in pending status.